# How can I use Foundation's equalizer to equalize a button inside a card

Tags: html, css

I have a card that I'm trying to get the button to go to the bottom of the card to match the card next to it using the equalizer from Foundation. I have the equalizer working on the card's background but have been unsuccessful in getting it to work on the button. I tried doing the nesting solution it gives in their documentation but was unsuccessful. How can I get my button to match the height of other card?

Here is my code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 80rem;
  margin: 0rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  list-style: none;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.test-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: visible;
}

.grid-col {
  display: block;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
  grid-column-end: span 1;
  position: relative;
}

.test-card-body {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin-top: -6.375rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  /* max-width: 80rem; */
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.button {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" data-equalizer="x0bwi9-equalizer" data-events="mutate" data-mutate="x0bwi9-equalizer" data-resize="x0bwi9-equalizer">
  <div class="grid-col test-card"><img alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/M8TXxQ5/Untitled-1.jpg" />
    <div class="test-card-body container" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 342px;">
      <h2>Text</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>

      <div>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><button class="button">Button</button></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-col test-card"><img alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/M8TXxQ5/Untitled-1.jpg" />
    <div class="test-card-body container" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 342px;">
      <h2>Text</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>

      <div>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><button class="button">Button</button></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are looking for something like this.

```
.TempClass {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
}
```

I added the above-given css to get the button to go to the bottom of the card

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 80rem;
  margin: 0rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  list-style: none;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.test-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: visible;
}

.grid-col {
  display: block;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
  grid-column-end: span 1;
  position: relative;
}

.test-card-body {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin-top: -6.375rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  /* max-width: 80rem; */
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.button {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.TempClass {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" data-equalizer="x0bwi9-equalizer" data-events="mutate" data-mutate="x0bwi9-equalizer" data-resize="x0bwi9-equalizer">
  <div class="grid-col test-card"><img alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/M8TXxQ5/Untitled-1.jpg" />
    <div class="test-card-body container" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 342px;">
      <h2>Text</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>

      <div>
        <p class="TempClass" style="text-align: center;"><button class="button">Button</button></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-col test-card"><img alt="" src="https://i.ibb.co/M8TXxQ5/Untitled-1.jpg" />
    <div class="test-card-body container" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 342px;">
      <h2>Text</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat vel ducimus illo consectetur commodi ex nulla aut amet ipsum maiores itaque, iusto quam mollitia facilis consequatur tempora neque quod eligendi?</p>

      <div>
        <p class="TempClass" style="text-align: center;"><button class="button">Button</button></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This almost works. The equalizer doesn't work properly on here so when I put it somewhere where it does work it the equalizer puts the button behind the last line of text so I think it views it as the same element now rather than an additional element. If I remove absolute from the class it goes back but then the button on the second card is no longer at the bottom.